# How can I differentiate device types found in /proc/partitions?

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I want to write a C++ function that can give me a list of hard drives in a machine (running Linux), but I want to filter out any USB flash drives.

When I read /proc/partitions I find sda and sdb, but I think that is not enough to differentiate between the primary hard drive and the USB flash drive. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the symlinks in:

```
/sys/block
```

For example, I have:

```
$ ll
 ...
 sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
 sde -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.2/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sde
 sdf -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.1/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/host8/target8:0:...
 sr0 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0
 sr1 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/host6/target6:0:1/6:0:1:0/block/sr1
```

You can spot the USB device in there pretty easily.

Look at the directories pointed to by those symlinks, there's a bunch of useful information there as well.